# Determine the formulae of the compositions $T \circ S$ and $S \circ T$ whenever they are defined.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine the formulae of the compositions $T \circ S$ and $S \circ T$ whenever they are defined.

$S:\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R^3 $ such that $S(\pmatrix{x\\y})=\pmatrix{x+y\\x-y\\x};$

$T:\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R^2$ such that $T(\pmatrix{x\\y})=\pmatrix{x+y\\x-y}.$

I am mainly confused about the part regarding 'defined'. I have looked through my notes but they don't seem to contain any information about that.

I have also attempted to solve for the compositions below:

$T \circ S(\pmatrix{x\\y})=T(\pmatrix{x+y\\x-y\\x})=\pmatrix{x+y+(x+y)\\x+y-(x-y)}=\pmatrix{2x\\2y}$

$S \circ T(\pmatrix{x\\y})=S(\pmatrix{x+y\\x-y})=\pmatrix{x+y+(x-y)\\x+y-(x-y)\\x+y}=\pmatrix{2x\\2y\\x+y}$

I can't seem to grasp what they mean about the above being defined or not. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: $T\circ S$ is not defined. The domain of $T$ is not the codomain of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote here:

$$T \circ S(\pmatrix{x\\y})=T(\pmatrix{x+y\\x-y\\x})=\pmatrix{x+y+(x+y)\\x+y-(x-y)}=\pmatrix{2x\\2y}$$

cannot be correct since $S$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $T$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is what the assignment means by *whenever defined*.

The other way around it works of course since $T$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. But here also you got confused: You wrote:

$$S \circ T(\pmatrix{x\\y})=S(\pmatrix{x+y\\x-y})=\pmatrix{x+y+(x-y)\\x+y-(x-y)}=\pmatrix{2x\\2y\\x+y} $$

The last equation cannot be true. A $2$-component vector cannot equal a $3$-component vector.

Comment: Oh, I missed out the third component for that composition -- I will edit it in shortly. Also, thanks for clarifying my doubts, I understand this now! (: